# Search for greek chars also returns latin chars

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, character-encoding

I'm running this in MySQL:

```
SELECT id, action FROM table1 WHERE action in ('α','δ','μ','Α','Δ','Μ')
```

Notice that the chars are Greek and also, I'm using utf-8 everywhere.
Why does this query also return rows where action = 'a' or 'A' (latin)??

This is the entire script:

```
$query = "SELECT id, action FROM table1 WHERE action in ('α','δ','μ','Α','Δ','Μ') ORDER BY id ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $totalRows_result = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($totalRows_result > 0) {
        do { 
            $str = $row['action'];
            $greek = array('α','δ','μ','Α','Δ','Μ');
            $latin = array('A','D','M','A','D','M');
            $validstr = str_replace($greek, $latin, $str);

            $q = "UPDATE table1 SET action='$validstr' WHERE id='".$row['id']."'";  
            $res = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());           
        } while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following:

after you connect to the mysql, do this query to make sure that you are using UTF8:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
```

OR See if this can help you

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); ?>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

You can try this

```
<?php 
$link1 = mysql_connect('localhost','user1','pass1',TRUE); 
mysql_selectdb('db1',$link1); 
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link1); 
?>
```

Comment: use `mysql_set_charset`..but better use `PDO` or `mysqli`

Answer (score 0):

use `mysql_set_charset('utf8');`